# urllib2 and wget returns HTTP 403 (forbidden), while browser returns OK

Tags: python, http-headers, httprequest, urllib2, http-status-code-403

There is a webpage that my browser can access, but  `urllib2.urlopen()` (Python) and `wget` both return HTTP 403 (Forbidden). Is there a way to figure out what happened?

I am using the most primitive form, like `urllib2.urlopen("http://test.com/test.php")`, using the same url (http://test.com/test.php) for both the browser and `wget`. I have cleared all my cookies in browser before the test.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried it it prints `success bla` what system and what version of python are you running.

Comment: the site might be hindering a screen scraping. See `http://test.com/robots.txt`. Try to change User-Agent header.

Comment: @enginefree I don't think that OP meant `http://test.com/test.php` literally.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian what else can they do to hinder screen scraping? I have made the headers exactly the same as what I saw from LiveHTTPheaders

Comment: Does it work if you turn off javascript, flash, images in the browser?

Comment: CodeNoob, at the end how you solved this issue?, Which proposal you followed @Spaceghost or user1787687 one?. Thanks

Comment: @trinchet I ended up using user1787687's, i.e. Python requests library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sites dont allow web scraping. Try using [Python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

This library should work.

Comment: Thanks, but what's the fundamental difference between requests and urllib2? it's still about building an HTTP request and send it out, right>?

Answer (score 2):

The Python library urllib has a default user-agent string that includes the word Python in it and wget uses "wget/VERSION".  If the site you are cionnectiing checks the user-agent info, it will probably reject these two. Google, for instance, will do so.

It's easy enough to fix.. for wget, use the -U parameter and for urllib, create a URLOpener with an appropriate string.

Comment: Or check robots.txt file first

Comment: The robots.txt file is an opt-in - crawlers are not required to check it - and a match between User-Agent for a crawler and the contents of the file will not cause the server to return 403.